# HDFS AuthorizationException

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

Please help me to understand why I have problem with datanode connection below:

> WARN server.AuthenticationFilter
>   (AuthenticationFilter.java:doFilter(588)) - Authentication exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException:
>   GSS Exception: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level:
>   Checksum failed) WARN datanode.DataNode
>   (BPServiceActor.java:retrieveNamespaceInfo(227)) - Problem connecting
>   to server: s-*-t-*.*.ru/10.243.*.*:8020

I have kerberized cluster and everything works fine but I need to add new datanode and I have connection problem only with new datanode. 
On namenode I have next messages:

> INFO ipc.Server (Server.java:authorizeConnection(2235)) - Connection
>   from 10.243.218.16:33435 for protocol
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DatanodeProtocol is
>   unauthorized for user dn/s-*-t-*.*.ru@*.RU
>   (auth:PROXY) via $J4LB00-3PQ0LQ7EGVSG@*.RU (auth:KERBEROS)
>   2020-02-05 09:37:20,172 INFO ipc.Server (Server.java:doRead(1006)) -
>   Socket Reader #1 for port 8020: readAndProcess from client
>   10.243.218.16 threw exception [org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: User:
>   $J4LB00-3PQ0LQ7EGVSG@*.RU is not allowed to impersonate
>   dn/s-*-t-*.*.ru@*.RU]

So what the most interesting things it is a User: $J4LB00-3PQ0LQ7EGVSG@*.RU it the same dn/s-*-t-*.*.ru user but pre-win 2000 logon name

Is it right things? 
What else interesting i don't have problem with other elder datanode only with this one.

Comment: Did you copy configs (hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml) to the new node? Check that `hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups` and `hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts` are both `*`?

Comment: this what i checked first
<property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>

Comment: maybe something with sssd or AD ?

Comment: Check `hadoop.security.auth_to_local` and `/L` to lowercase the name?

Comment: Active Directory does not allow to create directly an account for a Kerberos SPN (service principal name e.g `HTTP/host@Realm` -- here `dn` stands for DataNode) ; you must create a dummy account, then "attach" a SPN to it. And a single SPN otherwise Java fails to manage the connection later. I guess your AD admin messed up the account creation or keytab retrieval, that stuff should be automated via Cloudera Manager or Ambari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ran into exactly the same issue this week on our cluster, affecting all nodes!

In [HDP 3.1.4 release notes](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/release-notes/hdp-release-notes.pdf)  on page 72 we found a known issue regarding **Open JDK 8u242**:

> Description of the problem or behavior 
>   Open JDK 8u242 is not supported as it causes Kerberos failure.
>   Workaround Use a different version of Open JDK

We figured out that we did an upgrade to 8u242 in the beginning of the week and downgraded to openjdk-8-jdk=8u162-b12-1.

That fixed the problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this. I investigated the issue on a HDP 3.1.4 cluster for a few hours but could not grasp what was going on. Downgrading JDK fixed it.

This OpenJDK 8 242 release is causing more issues. We had to rollback to OpenJDK 8u232 for HDF (Nifi) as well for an issue with Nifi Site-to-site connections giving timeouts, not Kerberos related. Symptom was that TCP sessions to the raw port were in state SYN_RECV.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading is not a real fix. We have been hit by the same problem so I reported it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1861883

I also reported this to the OpenJDK bug report site (twice) but no reaction so far.